# Colocar de manera vertical inputs mediante flexbox

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Buenas he creado un pequeño formulario de contacto y no entiendo porque los `inputs` **no** se me colocan por columnas.

Para intentar eso empleo `flexbox` , concretamente al contenedor de los `inputs` con identificador `id="Fila3Formulario"`, lo declaro `display: flex` y le aplico un `flex-direction:column`.

¿Acaso no debería todo el contenido de dicho contenedor colocarse por columnas?

```css
#ModalContacto {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#Formulario {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #e0e7e9;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 30px 250px;
  grid-template-columns: 90% 5%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ClassFormulario {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ClassFormulario span {
  background-color: #354649;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.uno {
  /*    background-color: aqua;*/
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

#Fila3Formulario {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

#Fila3Formulario input {
  height: auto;
  width: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Fila3Formulario textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ModalContacto">
  <div id="Formulario">

    <div class="ClassFormulario Fila1Formulario">
      <img src="img/LogosGimnasios/PowerProject.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="ClassFormulario Fila1Formulario">
      <span id="CerrarFormulario">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="ClassFormulario uno Fila1Formulario">
      <p> Formulario de contacto</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ClassFormulario uno" id="Fila3Formulario">
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos*">
        <input type="tel" placeholder="e-mail*">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Teléfono">
        <textarea placeholder="¿Que quieres saber?*"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Salud!

Answer (score 2):

Ten en cuenta que al definir un contenedor flex el comportamiento aplica a los elementos hijos de éste.

En tu caso el único hijo del `div` `Fila3Formulario` es el elemento `form`, por lo que es éste elemento el que se posiciona.

Si lo que quieres es alinear los elementos `input` deberías definir el comportamiento en un padre directo de éstos:

```css
#ModalContacto {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#Formulario {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #e0e7e9;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 30px 250px;
  grid-template-columns: 90% 5%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ClassFormulario {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ClassFormulario span {
  background-color: #354649;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.uno {
  /*    background-color: aqua;*/
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

#Fila3Formulario {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

#Fila3Formulario input {
  height: auto;
  width: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Fila3Formulario textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ModalContacto">
  <div id="Formulario">

    <div class="ClassFormulario Fila1Formulario">
      <img src="img/LogosGimnasios/PowerProject.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="ClassFormulario Fila1Formulario">
      <span id="CerrarFormulario">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="ClassFormulario uno Fila1Formulario">
      <p> Formulario de contacto</p>
    </div>

    <form action="">
      <div class="ClassFormulario uno" id="Fila3Formulario">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos*">
        <input type="tel" placeholder="e-mail*">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Teléfono">
        <textarea placeholder="¿Que quieres saber?*"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solo cambia el id del div que encierra al formulario y colocacelo al form:**

```
<div class="ClassFormulario uno" id="">
        <form action="" id="Fila3Formulario">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos*">
          <input type="tel" placeholder="e-mail*">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Teléfono">
          <textarea placeholder="¿Que quieres saber?*"></textarea>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
```

**Tendras que hacer algunas modificaciones de medida porque se deforma un poco**
**al colocarselo al div, el form quedaria como hijo y entonces el form es el que se posicionaria en columna (pero como el form solo es una sola columna)**